# Redux - Asynchronous response from web socket request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a websocket interface which I implemented so that I can use to send requests.
The problem is that the response is asynchronous and it initially returns the empty array because `retObj` is not updated from the callback function that I sent in. How can I make this function so that it will return the populated array when it has been updated.
This is how my Service looks like:

```js
import * as interface from '../webSocket'

const carService = () => {
  return {
    getCars: () => {
      interface.sendRequest(function (returnObject) {
       //
      }).then(d => d)
    }
  }
}

export default carService()
```

And this is how my action looks like:

```js
import { GET_CARS } from '../constants'
import carService from '../carService'

export const getCars = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const cars = await carService.getCars()
    console.log("At cars actions: ", cars) // logs: Array []
    dispatch(getCarsSuccess(cars))
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error: ', err)
  }
}

const getCarsSuccess = (cars) => ({
  type: GET_CARS,
  payload: cars
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I was looking at this answer for a while, but could not make it to work for me and that is why I posted the question. But forgot to mention that I was looking at this thread.

Comment: It should work, show us how you tried to implement it

Comment: I tried to use then as you can see at the carService function, but then it never arrives at car actions because it never logs "At car actions ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to wrap your callback into promise, since it was not a promise to begin with, which is why you cannot use `then` or `await`

```
import * as interface from '../webSocket'

const carService = () => {
  return {
    getCars: () => {
      return new Promise(resolve => interface.sendRequest(function (returnObject) {
       resolve(returnObject.msg)
      }));
    }
  }
}

export default carService()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you cant `await` a function unless it returns a Promise. So, as you can guess, the problem lies in `carService.getCars`'s definition. Try this:

```
getCars: () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    interface.sendRequest(function(returnObject) {
      // if theres an error, reject(error)
      resolve(returnObject);
    })
  })
}
```

Or, if sendRequest os am async function, simply return the return value of `sendRequest`:

```
getCars: () => {
  return interface.sendRequest()
}
```